# routing action within mvc4 area not able to map action

Tags: asp.net-mvc, c#-4.0, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-mvc-routing

I am having trouble trying to get a route working in an area I have.

My area is called ABC and I have a controller called Home within the area. I am able to hit the breakpoint with Home/Index if I browse "http://localhost:8000/abc" however when I try hit another action called details like "http://localhost:8000/ABC/details" I get a 404.

I have tried

```
context.MapRoute(
           "details",
           "ABC/Home/{action}/{id}",
           new { action = "details", id = UrlParameter.Optional },
             constraints: null,
           namespaces: new[] { "WebApplication.Areas.ABC.Controllers" }

       );



        context.MapRoute(
          "ABC_Home",
          "ABC/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
          new { controller = "home",action="Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional },
            constraints: null,
            namespaces: new[] { "WebApplication.Areas.ABC.Controllers" }
      );
```

This allows me to hit the action if I use "http://localhost:8000/ABC/Home/Details"

```
 context.MapRoute(
           "details",
           "Home/Home/{action}/{id}",
           new {controller="home", action = "details", id = UrlParameter.Optional },
             constraints: null,
           namespaces: new[] { "WebApplication.Areas.ABC.Controllers" }

       );
```

Ideally I don't want to use home within the url if possible. What am I doing wrong?

Any help would be awesome!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you would just need a single route for this.  Don't include the controller in the route, since it seems to be implied by starting with */ABC*; just assign the controller as a default value:

```
context.MapRoute(
    "ABC_Home",
    "ABC/{action}/{id}",
    new { controller = "home", action="Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional },
    constraints: null,
    namespaces: new[] { "WebApplication.Areas.ABC.Controllers" }
}
```

Per your requirements, this will route */abc* to */home/index*, and will route */abc/details* to */home/details*.

Then, if you need to access other controllers you can add another rule for that, something like the default one:

```
context.MapRoute(
    "Default_Route",
    "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
    new { id = UrlParameter.Optional }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can default a controller with a variable action name, otherwise there's no way to tell from the routes that it is an action or controller and which route to match.  I think you could hard-code the action though:

```
Context.MapRoute(
    "ABC_Home_Details",
    "ABC/Details/{id}",
    new { controller = "home", action="details", id = UrlParameter.Optionsl },
    constraints: null,
    namespaces: new [] { "WebApplication.Areas.ABC.Controllers" }
);
```